# .Compute for Standard Deviation

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, calculation

I have a question that I was unable to find while googling.

I have a datatable whose size will fluctuate depending on raw data we have for a clinical study.

```
        public double calculateInterCv()
    {
        object DeviationCalculated = DataToCalculate.Compute("StDev([Mean])", "");
        object grandMeanCalculated = DataToCalculate.Compute("Avg([Mean])", "");
        double deviation = Convert.ToDouble(DeviationCalculated);
        double grandMean = Convert.ToDouble(grandMeanCalculated);
        double interCv = (deviation / grandMean) * 100;

        return interCv;
    }
```

As you can see I am using the .Compute("stDev([])") to compute all entries in the Mean table.  I did a comparison of the data and it seems off.  Does anyone know if the stDev uses the n-1 to find the standard deviation or if it is just n?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself.  For those interested the standard deviation did not display the correct value in line 1.  The below is what gave us the correct values.

```
    public double CalculateStandardDeviation()
    {
        int count = DataToCalculate.Count;

        double average = DataToCalculate.Average();
        double sum = DataToCalculate.Sum(d => Math.Pow(d - average, 2));
        double deviation = Math.Sqrt(sum / (count-1));

        return deviation;
    }
```